# Split data in one column of data into two other columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change my Excel data from single column to multiple columns using VBA.

My Input data (Column A1):

[image: Input]

I wish my output (Column C1 and D1)

[image: Output]

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* Is there a particular reason this needs to be done with VBA? This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a *specific* problem after trying to solve it on their own. If, after **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)**, you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post to share [examples of your code and relevant data](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some background info. Some good reading to get you started: "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)**. Also see the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a, e, x

a = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    .CompareMode = 1
    .Item("Item") = "Count"

    For Each e In a
        If e <> "" Then
            For Each x In Split(e, ", ")
                .Item(Trim(x)) = .Item(Trim(x)) + 1
            Next x
        End If
    Next e

    a = Application.Transpose(Array(.keys, .items))
End With

Sheet1.Range("C1").Resize(UBound(a, 1), 2).Value = a
End Sub
```

Comment: Hallo, i still have some problem.. script only showing COUNT, can we change to SUM?

and i want to remove Qty on ending CODE
can you help me ?